# Mongoose find subdocument in array and update it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi guys i have problem that i fail to solve.
How can i find and update a singel subdocument in a array if i dont have the _id or do i need the _id?
If i dont need the _id how can i find the subdocument in the array with example userId in this case and update the data fields.

```
const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  }, 
   data1: { type: String },
   data2: { type: String }
});

const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
orderId: {
    type: Number,
    require: true
  },
list: [listSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Test", testSchema);
```

I have tryed something like this but i then get all the "list" obj and i cant find out how to get a singel
"list" obj that have UserId: 1 lets say

```
try {
 await Test.findOne({ orderId: OrderId },"list");
} catch (err) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Test.findOne({ orderId: orderId, "list.userId": "1" })
```

More details here on how to query an array of sub-documents: [Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)